# Using wildcards in file path

Tags: powershell

I need to search a server for some files... but the file in question is buried in a folder that is under user IDs.  So I am trying to wildcard %username% to get to the folder I want to search.

Tired using %username% and * to wildcard the upper folder to get through to the subfolder.

```
$Path="\\server\profiles\%username%\Data\"
$filename='notes.ini'

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Filter $filename -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

I'm hoping to just search the Data folder for the notes.ini file and not having to search all the folders in between.

Comment: Are you looking to search every user's folder or a specific user?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know the name of the user, you can use the wildcard asteriks `*` in the path

```
$Path     = "\\server\profiles\*\Data\"  #"# use wildcard to search all user folders 
$filename = 'notes.ini'

# this returns the full file and path names of the file you are looking for:
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Filter $filename -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

If this is not what you are after, please add some more explanation in your question.

Answer (score 0):

%username% in powershell is $env:username

%username% isn't a wildcard, it's an environment variable in cmd